# why div with id = sub display value is "" instead of none

Tags: javascript, html, css

in this code css display property div with id="sub" has changed to none, but after running js code it shows its css display value for it  is empty("")

```
<head>
<style>
    #title {
        height: 60px;
        background-color: green;
    }  
    #sub {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: orange;
        display: none ;
    }
<!-- display for sub set to none-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title"  onmousedown= "showhide('sub')"></div>
    <div id= "sub"  ></div>

<script>
    function showhide(box)  {
        var border = document.getElementById(box);
        alert('div '+ box+' got');


    if(border.style.display ==="" ){
        alert( border.style.display);
        alert ('if is true so display changes to block');
        border.style.display = "block";

    }
    else{
        alert( border.style.display);
        alert ('else is true so display changes to " "');
        border.style.display = "";
   }         
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
var elem = document.getElementById(box);
if (elem.currentStyle) {
    var displayStyle = elem.currentStyle.display;
} else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display");
}
alert(displayStyle);
```